# ESLint (in VSCode) + Gulp Include

Tags: gulp, eslint

I'm using the [ESLint extension for VSCode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint). I'm also using [Gulp Include](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-include) to concatenate my JS files. ESLint doesn't seem to understand Gulp Include's way of pulling files in, such as:

```
//=require third-party/jquery.min.js
```

As a result, it gives a whole tonne of no-undef errors for things that are defined in my included JS files.

I can tell ESLint top ignore no-undef errors, but that's not ideal. Has anyone got it to work with Gulp Include? Maybe it'd be easier if I was using Gulp ESLint, but I love how it works in VSCode. This seems like it should be quite a common problem but I can't find anything about it!

Thanks loads for any help.